# Using 2 middleware functions in one post

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

Is there any way to use 2 middleware functions like this:

```
route.post('/login', auth.isAuthenticated, multer.any(), function(req,res) {
  res.send("bla bla bla");
}
```

Can I use both `auth.isAuthenticated` and `multer.any()` (for uploading files)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to pass an array of middleware callbacks you'd like to have executed like this according to the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD):

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD

> **router.METHOD(path, [callback, ...] callback)**

```
route.post('/login', [auth.isAuthenticated, multer.any()], function(req, res) {
    res.send("bla bla bla");
});
```

**Update:**

You may need to structure where all callbacks are within the array brackets `[]`:

```
route.post('/login', [auth.isAuthenticated, multer.any(), function(req, res) {
    res.send("bla bla bla");
}]);
```

You could also consider using `app.use()` to register callbacks like so:

```
var route = express.Router();

var require = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: '/some/path' });

route.use(auth.isAuthenticated);
route.use(upload.any());

app.use("/login", route);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: but what if I just wanted to use middleware for only 1 route ? can I handle with that by using route.use(auth.isAuthenticated); I mean that if I do that all my routes will connected to that middleware or it is different ?

Comment: You are correct, `.use()` would be for **all** HTTP verbs, so it may not be ideal/valid for specific situations. I've updated my answer to show how it would only apply to route "/login". The example I provided would be all HTTP verbs for route "/login" when using `use()`. Thanks!